# Haystack Tutorial 1 - Libraries Incompetalibity

Tags: haystack

I am trying Haystack tutorial 1 - https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial1_Basic_QA_Pipeline.ipynb on Google Colab and I am getting the following incompatibility errors during the installation

Command

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack.git
!pip install urllib3==1.25.4
```

Errors

```
Successfully built farm-haystack langdetect python-multipart python-docx tika seqeval databricks-cli prometheus-flask-exporter alembic
ERROR: torchvision 0.9.1+cu101 has requirement torch==1.8.1, but you'll have torch 1.7.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: torchtext 0.9.1 has requirement torch==1.8.1, but you'll have torch 1.7.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pytest 3.6.4 has requirement pluggy<0.8,>=0.5, but you'll have pluggy 0.13.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: botocore 1.20.84 has requirement urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4, but you'll have urllib3 1.24.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: grpcio-tools 1.37.1 has requirement grpcio>=1.37.1, but you'll have grpcio 1.34.1 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by using

```
!pip install grpcio-tools==1.34.1
```